# Xcode - Could not launch 'watch app WatchKit App' on iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

I have Xcode version 9.2. When trying to run the app on my Apple Watch(1 Series), I get this error:

"Could not launch 'watch app WatchKit App' on iPhone

There was an error preparing Apple Watch for development.

Try reattaching the device to which Apple Watch is paired. Could not locate device support files. [This Apple Watch 42mm is running watchOS 4.3.2 (15U70), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.]"

I went to /Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/DeviceSupport

4.2 is the latest device support I see.

Can I download 4.3 device support and importing to Xcode? I don't want to upgrade my Xcode because I am running a VM.

I had success with my iPhone from this URL https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport.

I searched WatchOS 4.3 without success.

Comment: how do u solve the problem finally?